# Prevent Smart UV Project From Using Same Texture for Two Parts

Tags: uv

I am trying to use smart UV project to unwrap a model. The issue is I want every triangle to be assigned a unique area on the UV map, but in the gLTF file that's imported, two objects are set to use the same mesh, so I think because of this, it assigns them to the same areas on the texture. Is there a way I can force it to give every part a unique texture region?

Comment: You can select both the 2 objects, switch to Edit mode and unwrap, the UVs won't overlap